# Why does omitting a 0ms sleep break my css transition?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, transition

I was trying to implement the [FLIP](https://www.julianburr.de/til/flip-animation-technique/) animation, to see if I understood it properly.

In this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dazzaondmic/pen/bGjEzXO) (pardon the awful code, I was just hacking around), if I comment out the sleep, the smooth transition no longer works. The div changes position abruptly. This is strange because the sleep is for 0ms.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "https://esm.sh/react@18";
import ReactDOM from "https://esm.sh/react-dom@18";

let first = {}
let second =  {}

const sleep = async (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const App = () => {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(true);
  
  const boxRefCb = async el => {
    if (!el) return;

    el.style.transition = "";
    const x = parseInt(el?.getBoundingClientRect().x, 10);
    const y = parseInt(el?.getBoundingClientRect().y, 10);
    first = { x: second.x, y: second.y };
    second = { x, y };
    
    const dx = first.x - second.x;
    const dy = first.y - second.y;

    const transStr = `translate(${dx}px, ${dy}px)`;
    el.style.transform = transStr;
    await sleep(0); // comment me out
    el.style.transition = "transform .5s";
    el.style.transform = "";
  }
  
  return (
    <>
    <div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "1rem", padding: "3rem"}}>
      <div ref={ start ? boxRefCb : null } style={{ visibility: start ? "" : "hidden", width: 100, height: 100, border: "solid 1px grey" }}></div>
      <div  ref={ !start ? boxRefCb : null } style={{ visibility: !start ? "" : "hidden", width: 100, height: 100, border: "solid 1px grey" }}></div>
    </div>
      
    <button style={{ marginLeft: "3rem"}} onClick={() => setStart(start => !start)}>start | {start.toString()}</button>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

I suspect this is some event loop magic that I don't understand. Could someone shed some light onto this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the browser may have time to recalculate the CSSOM boxes (a.k.a "perform a reflow"), during that `sleep`. Without it, your `transform` rule isn't ever really applied.
Indeed, browsers will wait until it's really needed before applying the changes you made, and update the whole page box model, because doing so can be very expensive.
When you do something like

```js
element.style.color = "red";
element.style.color = "yellow";
element.style.color = "green";
```

all the CSSOM will see is the latest state, `"green"`. The other two are just discarded.

So in your code, when you don't let the event loop actually loop, the `transStr` value is never seen either.

However, relying on a 0ms `setTimeout` is a call to issues, there is nothing that does ensure that the styles will get recalculated at that time. Instead, it's better to force a recalc manually. Some [DOM methods/properties](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) will do so synchronously. But remember that a reflow can be a very expensive operation, so be sure to use it sporadically, and if you have multiple places in your code in need of this, be sure to concatenate them all so that a single reflow is performed.

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".elem");
const move = () => {
  el.style.transition = "";
  const transStr = `translate(150px, 0px)`;
  el.style.transform = transStr;
  const forceReflow = document.querySelector("input").checked;
  if (forceReflow) {
    el.offsetWidth;
  }
  el.style.transition = "transform .5s";
  el.style.transform = "";
}
document.querySelector("button").onclick = move;
```

```css
.elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<label><input type=checkbox checked>force reflow</label>
<button>move</button>
<div class=parent>
  <div class=elem></div>
</div>
```

[Or with OP's code](https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/OJwNJKL).

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching this problem with a vanilla JavaScript solution, but React uses a virtual DOM and expects DOM elements to be re-rendered when state has been changed. Therefore, I'd recommend leveraging React state to update the element's XY position within the virtual DOM, but while still using CSS.

Working demo [here](https://s14n10.csb.app/) or the code can be found here:

[image: Edit React Transition Between Points]

---

```
import { useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

type BoxXYPosition = { x: number; y: number };

export default function App() {
  const startBox = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const startBoxPosition = useRef<BoxXYPosition>({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const endBox = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  const [boxPosition, setBoxPosition] = useState<BoxXYPosition>({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  });
  const { x, y } = boxPosition;
  const hasMoved = Boolean(x || y);

  const updatePosition = () => {
    if (!endBox.current) return;

    const { x: endX, y: endY } = endBox.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const { x: startX, y: startY } = startBoxPosition.current;

    // "LAST" - calculate end position
    const moveXPosition = endX - startX;
    const moveYPosition = endY - startY;

    // "INVERT" - recalculate position based upon current x,y coords
    setBoxPosition((prevState) => ({
      x: prevState.x !== moveXPosition ? moveXPosition : 0,
      y: prevState.y !== moveYPosition ? moveYPosition : 0
    }));
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // "FIRST" - save starting position
    if (startBox.current) {
      const { x, y } = startBox.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      startBoxPosition.current = { x, y };
    }
  }, []);

  // "PLAY" - switch between start and end animation via the x,y state and a style property
  return (
    <main className="app">
      <h1>Transition Between Points</h1>
      <div className="container">
        <div
          ref={startBox}
          className="box start-point"
          style={{
            transform: hasMoved
              ? `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) rotateZ(360deg)`
              : ""
          }}
        >
          {hasMoved ? "End" : "Start"}
        </div>
        <div className="end-container">
          <div ref={endBox} className="box end-point" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={updatePosition}
      >
        Move to {hasMoved ? "Start" : "End"}
      </button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: While I appreciate your response and you have some great tips in there, my question was specifically about the role of the sleep function and how it interacts with the event loop to cause my transition to be applied. My pure javascript solution was just a hacky script I used to learn about the FLIP animation technique. I would do something similar to what you've done if I was going to implement this in a real React project.